# Data disappears after being sent with segue using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller, segue

I am doing something very wrong, but I don't understand what.
So I sending my String like this:

```
var someString = "My String"
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "MyCustomIdentifier") {
        let vc = segue.destinationViewController as! MySecondViewController

        vc.someString = someString
    }
}
```

And MySecondViewController gets the value of someString:

```
var someString = String()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print(someString) //Prints String as expected, all good
}
```

But then when I need it to access in imagePickerController:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    print(someString) //Nothing is printed, there is no value in someString
}
```

What's happening here? I need that string value in `imagePickerController`, because I will be sending chosen image using Alamofire and that string is my header.

**EDIT:** Found the problem - I was getting my `someString` value from server at the same time as `prepareForSegue` was getting called.

Comment: Is `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` called at all? Is the delegate connected properly? Add some literal text in the print line to check that.

Comment: Yes, `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` is called - I have ImageView on MySecondViewController and it shows selected image (in example I excluded irrelevant (IMO) code). How delegate can be connected not properly? In UIStoryboard there is  "Show" segue with identifier "MyCustomIdentifier". What do you mean literal text? Like `print("this is literal text")`, I did that and it works as expected

Comment: Yes, because printing a variable containing an empty string prints nothing

Comment: I don't understand, why someString variable becomes empty in imagePickerController, but has value in viewDidLoad?

Comment: I think the value you're setting must be getting replaced at some point. To see when this is happening, try adding didSet to your property with a breakpoint like this: ```var someString = String() {
        didSet {
            /// Put a breakpoint here
        }
    }```

Comment: I don't know what happened, but now it works. I created breakpoint with `didSet` and the someString value was changing to nothing and then suddenly it started to work.
I also did "Undo Typing" for both view controllers to revert all changes made after posting my question and it still works

Answer (score 0):

Strings are value types in swift, therefore the second ViewController creates a brand new instance. Need to pass a reference, so try declare it in 2nd ViewController as an optional :

```
var someString : String!
```

Comment: Just tried it and got error:
`fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`

Comment: Hi Xernox
I just tested on Xcode 7.1 and it printed the string OK. I made 2 VCs with Show segue. Second VC inherits UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate and delegate connected of course (as I believe you did). It enters the picker and print the value OK. My second best advice - look that you don't touch that string anywhere in between (comment occurences or perform the didSet suggested above). Good Luck.